# How can I set up Typescript to import types from another Prisma folder?

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma, trpc.io

We're using [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org), [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) and [TRPC](https://trpc.io/) in two NodeJS services that need to communicate with each other. Both services have their own database, so the generated Prisma client in `node_modules` is different between the folders. The folder structure is set up like so:

```
.
├── service_1/
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── package.json
│   └── ...rest of project
└── service_2/
    ├── tsconfig.json
    ├── package.json
    └── ...rest of project
```

Because we're using TRPC, `service_1` imports types directly from `service_2` like the following example:

```js
import type { AppRouter } from '../../../../service_2/src/routers/index'
```

This works fine in VSCode, however we want to put typechecking as an CI action on `service_1`, but running `tsc -p ./tsconfig.json --noEmit` in the root of `service_1` shows a lot of errors like this:

```
../service_2/src/services/dog.ts:53:10 - error TS2339: Property 'dog' does not exist on type 'PrismaClient<PrismaClientOptions, never, RejectOnNotFound | RejectPerOperation | undefined>'.

53   prisma.dog.findMany({
```

We surmise that this is caused by Typescript using the generated `@prisma/client` package from the `service_1` folder even when typechecking `service_2`, but we've tried changing a number of options in our `tsconfig.json` to no avail.

Our current `tsconfig.json` in `service_1` looks like this:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "strict": true,
    "paths": {
      "/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules/*",
    "**/dist/*",
    "**/.git/*",
  ],
}
```

Some of the options we've tried include:

- Setting `rootDir` to `./`
- Setting `rootDir` to `../`
- Setting `rootDirs` to `["./", "../service_2"]`
- Adding `@ts-ignore` or `@ts-nocheck` above the type import
- Adding `service_2` to the `exclude` option

Is there a way to get typechecking across two projects like this with separate `node_modules` on one that imports from another?

Comment: The `@prisma/client` namespace clash can be avoided by [generating the client to a custom path](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/generating-prisma-client#the-location-of-prisma-client)